# How to make a search in codeiginiter without "like" paramameter?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, codeigniter

Model:

```
function search()
{
    $cari=$this->db->query("select * from uhd_user_order where user_order_reference  ");
    return $cari->result();;
}
```

Controller:

```
function search_keyword()
{
    $this->input->GET('cari', TRUE);
    $beda['cari'] = $this->order_test_m->search();
    $this->load->view('admin/a',$beda);
}
```

View:

```
<?php if(count($cari)>0){
    foreach ($cari as $row => $test) {
    }?>

    <?= $test->sendername ?>

    <?php
} ?>
```

I need to make a search, and the result of the view will show up if I put the right code only. Like, if I only search "s", the data from my database will not show up.

How can this be done?

Comment: Add your html code as well, where the search text field is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you want, I have some questions about your code, but I can not comment yet. I have to guess what happend:

**I think your code works as: Whenever the 'search' button is clicked, all of your user's name in your database will be displayed, right?**

Because your model does not use the 'get' data to search in the database

```
//Your function does not recieve the search string.
//This function uses $string to search in the 'users' table, to finds the name field == $string, and returns only 'name' row. 

function search($string){

    $query = $this->db->select('name')
        ->where('name',$string)
        ->get('users');

   //If the result is empty, return false, do nothing.
    if($query->num_rows() === 0){

        return false;
    }

    return $query->result();;
}
```

Controller

```
function search_keyword()
{
// Call search function with the input data.
// I think here will have some validation
//for example:
//if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
//       $this->load->view('errors/error');
//}
    $search_string = $this->input->GET('cari', TRUE); 
    $beda['cari'] = $this->order_test_m->search($search_string);
    $this->load->view('admin/a',$beda);
}
```

View:

```
// This will ensure the ul will only display when $cari is not empty.
<?php if(count($cari)>0):?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($cari as $row):?>
   <li><?php echo $row->name;?></li>
<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>>
```